# Can you identity a movie about friends trying to murder each other?

Tags: identify-this-movie, comedy

I was very little when I saw this movie but I haven't seen it since. The plot centers around two friends I believe who keep trying to kill each other. But it was a comedy I believe.

In one particular scene an old lady is yelling at one of them, maybe his mother. Then he turns and hits the guy with a frying pan. I somewhat remember this scene because after it happened, my grandmother started laughing hysterically.  It's stuck with me because I remember she was laughing so hard it made me laugh and is definitely a fond memory of mine. The only other thing I remember is at the end I think the guy choked the other one. I'm sorry if this is very vague.  I've been really wanting to find this movie because it's such a vivid memory of my grandma laughing that has always stuck with me.

If I had to put a timeframe of the movie I would say I saw it in the late eighties. It was definitely in color and a live action movie. I'm fairly certain it is an American movie also.

Comment: "friends"....:)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds a lot like [Throw Momma From The Train](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094142)

Here is the plot synopsis -

> Larry (Billy Crystal), an author with a cruel ex-wife, Margaret (Kate Mulgrew), teaches a writing workshop where Owen (Danny DeVito), one of his students, is fed up with his domineering mother (Anne Ramsey). When Owen watches a Hitchcock classic that seems to mirror his own life, he decides to put the movie's plot into action and offers to kill Margaret, if Larry promises to murder his mom. Before Larry gets a chance to react to the plan, it seems that Owen has already sealed Margaret's fate.

I remember a lot of physical comedy, both of the violent variety and the mother's short, hunched appearance as well as her voice and vocal mannerisms.

Definitely some frying pan humor, as well....

[YouTube frying pan vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1900A_ktEg)

Comment: That was my first thought as well. "You don't have a cousin Patty!". Iconic scene.

Comment: Oweeeeennnnnnn! Classic. RIP Ann Ramsey

Comment: @Andrew Mattson I'm so glad I joined this site! I've been looking for ages for this movie. That is the scene I remember! Finally seeing this and remembering my grandma laughing brought a tear to my eye. Did you remember this from seeing the movie? Thank you so much!

Comment: The "Hitchcock classic" the description refers to is *[Strangers on a Train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangers_on_a_Train_(film))*, which involves two strangers who both have someone they want dead. One of them suggests they kill each other's victims, then goes ahead and does his side. The other person has some serious regrets and doesn't want to follow through on his part of the "deal".

Comment: @ElBromista, the frying pan smack was in the trailers. Some of us are showing our age here... 

Comment: @ElBromista - yeah, getting creamed by a frying pan and the unpleasant mom definitely stirred memories from when I watched the movie. I can hear her voice, yelling "OWEN!!"